# Passing data(value) of form field from one route to another in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass data of a form in one component(view) to another component in another completely different component by routing to it but when i check my console in this view it just shows undefined(A method attached to the submit button logs prints out the data on the console). I click on a button which sends me to the second route but I am also using a data service to send the information in one of the form fields to another route.
Sender component

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Data }  from './data';

    @Component({
      selector: 'home-app',
      templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
      styles: [`
      i{color:white;margin-left:-90px;margin-top:2px;margin-right:12px;}
      .logo{margin-top:-10px;}
      #banner{margin:-18px;margin-top:-70px;transform:scaleY(0.85)}
      #btn{transform:scale(1.4)}
      #img{margin: 0; padding: 0;display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
      #imgcontainer p{ font-size: 32px; margin-left:-107px;}
      #imgcontainer{cursor:pointer}
      `],
    })
    @Injectable()
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
       public userName;
       onSubmit(){
         console.log(this.userName);
         this.router.navigate(['/makeyourlist'])
       }
    public constructor(private router: Router,private userData: Data){    
    this.userData.name = this.userName;
    }
     ngOnInit() { }
    }
```

The service.ts code

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    @Injectable()
    export class Data{
       public name: any;
       public constructor() { }
    }
```

The receiver component

```
            import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
            import { Router } from '@angular/router';
            // import { NameService } from './name.service';
            import { Data }  from './data';
            import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

            @Component({
                selector: 'to-do',
                templateUrl: 'todo.component.html',
                styles: [`
                   .body{background-color: #F4F4F4}
                   i{color:black;}
                   .logo{margin-top:-10px; padding:0;margin:0}
                   #img{transform:scale(0.4);margin-left:0px; 
                       padding:0;margin:0}
                   #side{background-color:grey;color:white;height:100%}
                   #i{font-size:20px;}

                `],

             })

             export class ToDoComponent implements OnInit{
                user(){
                    alert(this.userData.name);
                }
                public constructor(private userData:Data) {
                  console.log(this.userData.name);
                }
                ngOnInit() {}
             }
```

Comment: I think you want to look into activated routes. https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service

Answer (score 0):

don't use decorator `@Injectable()` in components. It's only for services.

I see you're trying to share data between components using service.ts.

That's ok. It's "Shared service".

It well-described here

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service